# What is a good "Error Checking" Pattern (Java)?

Tags: java, error-handling

I'll explain what I mean by input error checking.

Say you have a function `doSomething(x)`.

If the function completes successfully `doSomething` does something and returns nothing. *However, if there are errors I'd like to be notified.* That is what I mean by error checking.

I'm looking for, in general, the best way to check for errors. I've thought of the following solutions, each with a potential problem.

1. **Flag error checking.** If `doSomething(x)` completes successfully return `null`. Otherwise, it returns a boolean or an error string. **Problem:** Side effects.
2. **Throwing an exception.** Throw an exception if `doSomething(x)` encounters an error. **Problem:** If you are performing error checking for parameters only, throwing an `IllegalArgumentException`seems inappropriate.
3. **Validating input prior to function call.** If the error checking is only meant for the parameters of the function, then you can call a validator function before calling the `doSomething(x)` function. **Problem:** What if a client of the class forgets to call the validator function before calling `doSomething(x)`?

I often encounter this problem and any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: the notification is one part, but what do you do to handle the "error" (for instance for the 3rd proposition)? And also, how often the exception is going to be raised (if you choose this solution)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. **Flag error checking**

This is appropriate in some cases, depending on what you mean by an "error".

An example from the API: If you try to add an object to a `Set`, which already contains another object which `equals` the new object, the `add` method sort of "fails" and indicates this by returning `false`. (Note that we're on a level at which it's technically not even an "error"!)

> 2.**Throwing an exception**

This is the default option.

Question is now, should you go for a checked exception (which you need a `throws` declaration or `try`/`catch` clauses) or an unchecked exception (an exception that extends `RuntimeException`). There are a few rules of thumbs here.

From [Java Practices -> Checked versus unchecked exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129):

- **Unchecked exceptions:** Represent defects in the program (bugs) - often invalid arguments passed to a non-private method.
- **Checked exceptions:** Represent invalid conditions in areas outside the immediate control of the program (invalid user input, database problems, network outages, absent files)

Note that `IllegalArgumentException` is an *unchecked* exception, perfectly suitable for throwing when arguments are not as they should be.

If you want to throw a checked exception, you could A) roll your own by extending `Exception`, B) use some existing checked exception or C) "chain" a runtime exception in, for instance, an `IOException`: `throw new IOException(new IllegalArgumentException("reason goes here..."));`

> 3.**Validating input prior to function call**

Relying on the fact that the client should have sanitized / checked his arguments before the call seems like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 7):

Throw an exception is the best way.

> If you are performing error checking for parameters only, throwing an
>   IllegalArgumentException seems inappropriate.

Why? That's the purpose of this Exception.

Comment: Agreed, why would that be inappropriate?  It is an exceptional condition (I'm assuming), and the error is specific enough your client code can do something meaningful with it.

Comment: I should have clarified that the parameter error checking I had in mind was user input. From Effective Java: "Use runtime exceptions to indicate programming errors". As aiobee mentions below, runtime exceptions are for bugs rather than invalid user input.

Comment: You don't have to let the runtime exception trickle all the way up to the UI. You can trap it by the calling function and instead of re-throwing it, print a user-friendly message. For example, `tan(90 deg)` is undefined and the function should thrown an exception, but the calling function should convert the caught exception into a message for the user.

Comment: I understand your point. But have people often looked for a checked exception version of IllegalArgumentException? Do they create their own? The unchecked part is what bothers me about it.

Comment: It is inappropriate indeed RuntimeExceptions should be used to indicate programming errors. This should be a checked exception.

Comment: @Support, it does indeed indicate a programming error if the input to the method should have already been sanitized. You aren't passing unsanitized user input directly into unrelated methods... are you?

Comment: Makes sense, but I think Jacks is doing some kind of library.. mmmh ... and want to enforce clients to perform the validation.  May be may be :P

Answer (score 4):

Your second suggestion ("Throwing an exception") is the best choice. The other two options rely on the invoker either doing something before ("Validating input prior to function call") or after ("Flag error checking") the call to the method. Either way, the extra task is not mandated by the compiler so someone invoking the function isn't forced to call the "extra thing" so problems are not spotted till run-time.

As for "Throwing an Exception" and your suggested 'problem', well the answer is throw appropriate exception types for the code. If the input parameters are invalid, then throw an InvalidArgumentException (since that's the appropriate error). If the exception is for functionality (e.g. cannot open network connection), use another exception type or create your own.

Comment: My reputation is too low to add comments to other people's answers, but I agree with "stacker"s first bullet point (for User Interfaces).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with throwing exceptions.  I want to add another option that combines #2 and #3 - the **proxy pattern**.  That way your code stays fairly cohesive - validation in one place and business logic in another.  This makes sense if you have a large set of calls that need to be validated.

Create a [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) to handle validation.  Have it delegate all calls to the actual implementation of your business logic interface after it validates, otherwise it can throw exceptions if something does not validate.

Answer (score 1):

I decide which method to use usually on the type of interface.

- User interface (GUI): I validate before calling business methods, because the user wants to know what was wrong.
- On technical interfaces between components or systems, the interface should have been tested and work properly in this case I throw exceptions.

Comment: You should do both: client side **and** server side validation (don't trust the client!)

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions is the way to go.  Your stated problem with exceptions can be mitigated by the proper implementation of exception throwing / handling.  Use exceptions to your advantage by validating parameters at the lowest level that you need them and throwing an exception if the validation fails.  This allows you to avoid redundantly checking for validity at multiple levels in the call stack.  Throw the exception at the bottom and let the stack unroll to the appropriate place for handling the error.

Answer (score 1):

The method you choose depends on the situation, and they are not mutually exclusive so you can mix them all in the same solution (although whether that's a good idea really depends on your situation).

1. Choose this method if you want a very simple method for handling errors. This method might be OK for situations where the calling function can accept any value the called function returns. There might be situations where business logic dictates this as an OK choice, such as returning a specific message string when a resource cannot be properly located, or a server does not respond. Generally, I don't use this or see this technique in Java very much, as exceptions are a better mechanism for error handling.
2. Throw an exception when your function runs into un defined behaviour. If you have a math function that can only operate on positive integers and someone passes -1, you should thrown an InvalidArguementException. If your function is given the ID of a product in a database, but the product cannot be found by a query, you could throw a custom ProductNotFound exception.
3. Validating input is a good idea, I would say it should be done by the called function, rather than the caller - unless the caller can avoid an exception from the callee by validating the input before passing it. If you work in a language that supports Design By Contract, validating input would be done as the function's precondition.

I usually use #2 and #3. I haven't written code with error flags for a while. The exception to that might be a function that returned an enum, where one possible value indicated an error code. That was driven more by a business rule than anything else.

And generally, try to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a custom checked exception.

```
 doSomething(WithX x ) throws BusinessRuleViolatedException
```

Comment: Exceptions for flow control is an Anti-Pattern: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Answer (score 0):

Input validation is surprisingly complicated and all three of the suggested approaches in the original post are needed and sometimes more. Exceptions are appropriate when input is outside the bounds of business logic, if it is corrupt or cannot be read for example.

Flag checking quickly becomes an anti-pattern if you have more than one or two flags to check, and can be replaced with a slightly specialized version of the visitor pattern. I do not know the exact name of this specific pattern, but I'll informally call it the "**validator list pattern**" and will describe it in more detail below.

Checking input early and failing fast is usually good, but not always possible. Often there is a *lot* of input validation, all input received from outside of your control should be treated as hostile and requires validation. Good program design and architecture will help make it clear when exactly this needs to happen.

**'The Validator List Pattern'**

As an example, let's first describe in code the "Validation Flag" anti-pattern, and then we'll transform it to the "validation list" pattern.

```
public Optional<String> checkForErrorsUsingFlags( 
       ObjectToCheck objToCheck ) {
  // the small series of checks and if statements represent the
  // anti-pattern. Hard to test and many other problems crop up.
  String errMsg = checkForError1( objToCheck );
  if(errMsg != null ) {
    return Optional.of(errMsg);
  }
  errMsg = checkForError2( objToCheck );
  if(errMsg != null ) {
    return Optional.of(errMsg);
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}

/**** client usage  ****/
ObjectToCheck obj = doSomethingToReadInput(obj);
Optional<String> error = checkForErrors( obj);
if (error.isPresent()) {
  // invalid input, throw object away and request input again
} else {
  // do stuff, we have a valid input
}
```

To fix, start by creating a common interface that will represent a single validator. Then each check is converted to a validator instance. Finally we create a list of validators and pass it to the validator code.

```
/** The common validator interface each validator will use */
private interface MyValidator {
  public boolean isValid(ObjectToCheck obj);
  public String getErrorMessage(ObjectToCheck obj);
}

 // this method should look familiar to the above, now we 
 // have a list of validators as an additional parameter
public Optional<String> checkForErrors( ObjectToCheck objToCheck,
     List<MyValidator> validators ) {
  for(MyValidator validator : validators ) {
    if (!validator.isValid(objToCheck)) {
      String errMsg = validator.getErrorMessage(objToCheck);
      return Optional.of(errMsg);
    }
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}

/****** client usage  *****/
// now in this pattern, the client controls when the validators
// are created, and which ones are used.
MyValidator validator1 = new MyValidator() {
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(ObjectToCheck obj) {
    return checkForError1( objToCheck ) != null;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean getErrorMessage(ObjectToCheck obj) {
    return checkForError1( objToCheck );
  }
}
// note: above we call checkForError1 twice, not optimal.
// typical in real examples this can be avoided,
// and the error message generation logic split from the detection
// logic often simplifies things.
MyValidator validator2 = new MyValidator() { ... }

List<MyValidator> validators = 
  ImmutableList.of( validator1, validator2);
Optional<String> error = checkForErrors(objToCheck, validators);
if (error.isPresent()) {
    // invalid input, throw object away and request input again
} else {
    // do stuff, we have a valid input
}
```

Now to test, create a series of mock validators and check that each one has their validate called. You can stub validator results and ensure the correct behavior is taken. Then you also have access to each validator individually so you can test them one by one on their own. 
Cheers - hope that helps, happy coding.